# Laravel 5.5 Resource Controller and Dependecy Injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, containers

I am working on a Laravel 5.5 application. When I use `php artisan make:model SomeModel -mr` it creates the model, migration and resource controller.

I've been noticed that some methods have by default only one parameter: the model:

```
public function show(SomeModel $someModel)
{
    ...
}
```

If you look into the `$someModel` variable it has an empty **SomeModel** object.

I was reading on Laravel Documentation that it looks like the Containers or Facades but I am not sure how to use this. Do you?

**Edit 1:**

I had my routes defined in routes/web.php as: `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`

Now I had to define all the routes manually since automatic binding was not working:

```
Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('users/create', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('users', 'UserController@store');
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'UserController@edit', function(App\User $user) {});
Route::post('users/{user}', 'UserController@update', function(App\User $user) {});
Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'UserController@destroy', function(App\User $user) {});
```

So, should I replace every resource controller route to manual routing like this?

Answer (score 4):

The resource controller is expecting you to use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding). In your routes file, each route that corresponds to a controller action with an injected model will need to have a matching parameter.

For example:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

Using the above route, the following controller action would receive a user instances that corresponds to the user ID passed as a URL parameter.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The reason you're seeing an empty model now is that Laravel will just pass and fresh model to the controller if it is not bound to a route parameter. In other words, if you forget to bind the model in your routes file [automatic injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#automatic-injection) will just give you a new instance.

Note that if you are using a route resource the resulting routes should already have the correct parameters

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

You can run `php artisan route:list` to confirm that your actual routes are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my route it has been defined as `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');` so for instance when I access to the URL **user/1** it should bind the route to the action `UserController@show`. What I'v tried is to include an extra parameter to the method: `public function show($id, User $user)` so the `$id` is 1 (and it works). But `$user` have nothing.

Comment: @Maramal What do you get when you run `php artisan route:list`. You should either inject $id or $user, not both.

Comment: It is defined properly since I am accessing to the method. But just in case:
`users/{user}/                        | users.edit                | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show`

Comment: I would like to use only the User instance, but if I can't I need to use the id, but I'd like to understand it before.

Comment: @Maramal does your model name match your route parameter? If the route is `users/{user}` then the Model class name must be `User`, unless you are declaring the `getRouteKeyName()` method in your model.

Comment: yes, It does. As told before, all the routes and names have been generated automatically by Laravel Artisan command.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your controller is expecting two parameters like below:

```
   public function show($id, User $user)
```

if you try:

```
   public function show(User $user)
```

it should work correctly.

In your route you are passing only a single param like:

```
user/{user}
```

So if you dd the first param it will display the number 1 but if you pass that
to the model it will return the corresponding user as per what id you pass in the route.

The reason your `User` model was returning an empty object was because there was no value passed to it. 
Also make sure your route placeholder: `/{user}` matches the variable name in 
the controller:  `public function show(User $user)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I generated the controller it was only with one parameter: `show(User $user)`. I am trying to figure out and that's why I am passing to it two parameters, but only with One paramter is doesn't work.
If I do `show(User $id),` it will return to me an empty object.

Comment: This is incorrect. There is nothing preventing you from injecting both the raw route parameter and the bound model.

Comment: Ofcourse you can add as many params as you want, but make sure you match the route /user/{user} to the model User $user, the route param placeholder should match the variable name used to bind the model.

Comment: @DevinNorgarb I don't understand the suggestion to change `public function show($id, User $user)` to `public function show(User $user)` If route model binding is working correctly both of those will work.

Comment: As per my understanding you are then passing to few arguments in the route. It would then look like `user/{id}/{user}`.

And are you sure the placeholder in your route matches the name of the variable you are type hinting it to in the controller?

Comment: When using scaffolding to generate the resource controller it binds the routes automaicallly just defining `Route::resource('users', 'UserController')`, so you don't need to specify each `Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');`.Also, the generated resource has by default only one parameter and its `(User $user)`.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across with the same problem.
If your model having two or more words, you have to use only small letters like  $modeModel as $somemodel.

```
public function show(SomeModel $somemodel)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It was just an example... And I don't think it has anything to do or it's right.

Comment: This is a bug reported. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18167

Comment: Okay... but I don't have a real "someModel", I was using it as an example. Thanks anyway...